# Rails associations, how can I specify this relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

OS: Windows 7
Rails: 4.2.0

Hello, If I have two models lets say **Game**, and **Team**.

One game can have many teams, but teams can also belong to many games.

I can't seem to figure out the right way to do this, Belongs_to_many does not exist, and I don't think team can have_many games and game can have_many teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this:

- One is like @Alex Pan's answer: using `has_and_belongs_to_many`
- The other one is using `belongs_to` and `has_many` relation with a junction table.

  - in `game.rb`:

    - `has_many :game_team_maps`
    - `has_many :teams, through: :game_team_maps`
  - in `team.rb`

    - `has_many :game_team_maps`
    - `has_many :games, through: :game_team_maps`
  - in `game_team_map.rb`

    - `belongs_to :game`
    - `belongs_to :team`

In my opinion, the second way is more flexible and easier to maintain. I choose it for my own project.

There is a very detailed and useful cast from railscast that help you to solve this problem: http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

```
has_and_belongs_to_many
```

I believe is what you need

Answer (score 0):

has_and_belongs_to_many

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

Or you create a joining model (e.g. TeamMembership), that belongs_to Team and Game

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) association.

Your models should look like this:

```
class Games < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams #append this line to your model
end

class Teams < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games #append this line to your model
end
```

You will also want to create a join table for Games and Teams like so:

```
class CreateGamesTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :gamess_teams do |t|
      t.integer :game_id
      t.integer :team_id
    end
  end
end
```

Remember to run `rake db:migrate` to create this join table.

Answer (score 0):

While `has_and_belongs_to_many` is certainly a valid option, most "games" that I know of have a home team and an away team, so it might make sense to do something like:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: 'Team'
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :home_team_id
  has_many :away_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :away_team_id
end
```

You could also model it with a `has_many :through`:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_games
  has_many :games, through: :team_games
end

class TeamGame < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :team

  scope :home, -> { where(home: true) }
  scope :away, -> { where(home: false) }
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_games
  has_many :games, through: :team_games
  has_many :home_games, -> { TeamGame.home }, through: :team_games, source: :game, class_name: 'TeamGame'
  has_many :away_games, -> { TeamGame.away }, through: :team_games, source: :game, class_name: 'TeamGame'
end
```